# Removing blank spaces

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

My requirement is remove blank line from the address. I am doing it like this:

```
=Ucase(REPLACE(REPLACE(Fields!Address.Value, CHR(13), ""), CHR(10), ""))
```

[image: Screenshot]

It removes the blank line, however the line-breaks is inserted into the middle of the zip code:

> Hamilton, ON L8R
>
> 1E2 CAN

Comment: So first of all, can you just provide perfect value for `Fields!Address.Value` - and it's type. As I wanted to check here from my report builder. Also, have you try to choose placeholder html type instead of simple textbox?

Comment: I have to use simple text box

Comment: okay do one thing, double click on textbox text and check html radio button inside properties window. Also let me know if it helps you or not....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace the correct character to remove the line.

```
Try =UCASE(REPLACE(Fields!Address.Value, VBCRLF, ""))
```

That will replace all line feeds, if you only want to replace line feeds where there is an empty line you will need to look for VBCRLF + VBCRLF

```
=UCASE(REPLACE(Fields!Address.Value, VBCRLF + VBCRLF, VBCRLF))
```

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6415702/ssrs-2008-r2-carriage-return-problem) provides an alternative method of achieving the same result.